# jdbtemplet.qoeryForObject(String sql,RowMapper action)

Tags: jdbctemplate

String sql = "select * from customers where id = "+id;

```
Customer c =    jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Customers.class));
```

if the id exist it is returning an object perfect. But when the id does not exist I expect an object with null properties but it is throwing exception.
Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried by implementing the RowMapper and if(rs.next()) condition is always false even when the id is mutched. I think the cursor is moved one step in this method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use an sql aggregate function like:

```
String sql = "select max(*) from customers where id = "+id;
```

As `id` is supposed to be unique this will return either the value or null if no row is found.

Of cause, the other valid possibility is to catch and handle the exception.